# Express.js Project Bloat

Tags: node.js, express

By bloat I mean lots and lots of files accumulating in /views.

When I look at some of my applications I see huge amounts of templates and layouts within folders within /views. I often lose my mind when I'm trying to add these all to routes aswell as assign layouts.

I know Angular can prevent /views bloat, but I'm wondering if anyone has any tips or best practices to reduce views bloat or atleast make it more manageable in express.js alone?